# button event not firing in the aspx page including master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
    <asp:Button ID="btncomment"  text="Submit Now" Class="btn1" 
 runat="server" OnClick="btncomment_Click" CausesValidation="False"  />
```

When I run the page without using master page then button event fired but if i use the page with master page the button event doesnot fire.

```
main Registration = new main(); 
txtPassword.Text = pwdencrypt.Encrypt(txtPassword.Text, true);
string SQL2 = "insert into registration (fullname,email,phone_no,address,password,username) values ('" + txtfullname.Text + "','" + txtEmailAddress.Text + "','" + txtphone.Text + "','" + txtPAddress.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtuname.Text + "')";
Registration.saveData(SQL2);
Response.Write("You have successfully registered");
     }
```

Comment: Check your validation group and can you post your all code related to that butto

Comment: how to check validation group?

Comment: Can you post your design code

Answer (score 1):

set `"USeSubmitBehaviour=false" and "CauseValidation=false"`

The `UseSubmitBehavior` property specifies if the Button control uses the browser's built-in submit function or the ASP.NET postback mechanism.

[Button UseSubmitBehavior Property](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_usesubmitbehavior.asp)

When set to FALSE, ASP.NET adds a client-side script to post the form.
 This enables control developers to use the GetPostBackEventReference method to return the 
 client postback event for the Button.

Comment: I kept both of that you mentioned above but now problem is that the value of the textbox is showing null in the code behind.

Comment: :I have built function called as savedata to save in database.Here I didn't get why to use update instead of save?